# simplecarousel: adding array elements to the pagination ul

Tags: javascript, loops, carousel

I have a 2D array - "dbArray" - which is the data for Tobias Zeising's 'simplecarousel'. Each array inside dbArray is an array of 2 strings. I'd like to use the first string from each and put it inside the pagination buttons for the carousel. But I don't know how to do this without performing the same loop again in the pagination code. Can someone give me a clue?!

Here's my ajax building the array and initialising the carousel:

```
//--------------------------------------    
// COLLECT from db / build carousel
//--------------------------------------
$ajax_load.insertBefore('#content');
$.ajax({
    url: 'func/load-words.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(dbArray) {
        var items = '<ul id="carousel" class="carousel">';
        for (var i in dbArray) {
            items += '<li><h2>' + dbArray[i][0] + '</h2><p>' + dbArray[i][1] + '</p></li>';
        }
        items += "</ul>";                   
        $ajax_load.fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });

        $("#content").html(items).fadeIn('slow', function() {
        }); 

        $("#carousel").simplecarousel({
            fade: 100,
            pagination: true
        });

    }
});
```

and here's the pagination part of simplecarousel:

```
// include pagination
if(config.pagination != false) {
    container.after('<ul class="carousel-pagination"></ul>');
    var pagination = container.next('.carousel-pagination');
    for(var i=0;i<config.items;i++) {
        if(i==0)
            pagination.append('<li class="carousel-pagination-active">button</li>');
        else
            pagination.append('<li>button</li>');
    }

    pagination.find('li').each(function(index, item) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            slide(index,true);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have initially got it working by declaring a global paginationWords variable, and passing dbArray into this inside the ajax loop:

```
    success: function(dbArray) {
        var items = '<ul id="carousel" class="carousel">';
        paginationWords = dbArray;
        // etc...
```

Then inside the carousel pagination code I simply run off the loop again:

```
// include pagination    
if(config.pagination != false) {
    container.after('<ul class="carousel-pagination"></ul>');
    var pagination = container.next('.carousel-pagination');

    for(var i=0;i<config.items;i++) {
        if(i==0) 
            for (var n in paginationWords) {
                pagination.append('<li>'+paginationWords[n][0]+'</li>');
            }

            //pagination.append('<li class="carousel-pagination-active">button</li>');
        // else
            //pagination.append('<li></li>');
    }

    pagination.find('li').each(function(index, item) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            slide(index,true);
        });
    });
}
```